# State of the art for adding (nested) elements to the DOM and setting all attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the correct way to add some elements to the DOM?
This is how I did it so far:

```
$('#target').prepend('<div id="toolbar" data-id="' + id + '" class="' + class + '" style="width: ' + width + 'px; top: '+ pos.y +'px; left: '+ pos.x +'px;">'
    +'<i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>'
    +'<i class="fa fa-info"></i>'
    +'<i class="fa fa-link"></i>'
    +'<i class="fa fa-close"></i>'
    +'<div class="submenu" style="min-height: ' + size.height + 'px;">'
        +'<button class="btn btn-xs" data-type="Default">Default</button>'
        +'<button class="btn btn-xs" data-type="Second">Second</button>'
        +'<button class="btn btn-xs" data-type="Third">Third</button>'
    +'</div>'
+'</div>');
```

Maybe I have to create the main element first and add all subelements like this:

```
// create main element
$('<div/>', {
    id: 'toolbar',
    class: 'class'
})
.data('id', id)
.css({
    width: width + 'px',
    top: pos.y + 'px',
    left: pos.x + 'px'  
})
.appendTo('#target');

// create all icons in one loop
var icons = [ 'fa-chevron-down', 'fa-info', 'fa-link', 'fa-close' ];
$.each( icons, function( key, value ) {
    $('<i/>', {
        class: 'fa' + value
    }).appendTo('#toolbar');
});
```

As you see I mix up many possibilities. I would like to know which method should be used to be 'state-of-the-art' and with the best performance.
So if the second attempt should be better, I don't know if I shouldn't do

```
$('<div/>', {
    id: 'toolbar',
    class: 'class',
    data-id: id,
    style: cssObj
})
```

instead of using `data()`, `css()` and so on. On the other hand I could also use `addClass()`...

Comment: Do you mean state-of-the-art for jQuery or JavaScript in general?

Comment: Does it make a big (performance) difference? I'm more familiar with JQuery then plain JS.

Comment: Actually, there are frameworks that allow you to keep your HTML and JavaScript code separate. You can create reusable HTML templates and apply them using JavaScript data. Take a look at Knockout, AngularJS, or EJS, just to name a few. Each framework has its own approach and merits. Developers differ on which framework they prefer, of course. But in terms of "state of the art", I think you'll find a lot of dev teams using some kind of template framework. In my experience, building HTML in the JavaScript code (as in your examples) becomes a maintenance nightmare on a large project.